# Does the Graph API replaces Office 365 Reporting web service?

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I need to the following:

- Number of outbound mails per month
- Number of inbound mails per month
- Volume of outbound mail traffic (per month)
- Volume of inbound mail traffic (per month)
- Number of mail messages in organization
- Mailbox count
- Mailbox size for each user

In Office 365 Reporting web services I have the following reports:

- Mailbox Usage
- Mail Traffic

What API should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, reports are not exposed in Microsoft Graph API. This is currently in development and should be available in a few months.